# Angular.js app cousing inifinite digest loop within ng-repeat and makes site unresponsible

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having issue with digest loop and don't know how do I handle this thing in such a way that does not bring the site in unresponsible state. My code looks as below:

```
<div ng-controller="TeamController as tm">
   <div ng-repeat="team in tm.teams">
      <a href="">{{team.name}} - <span ng-init="tm.getTeamBusiness(team.id)">{{business.name}}</span></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is making site unresponsible, there might be more than 100 teams here and each iteration I am making a new request for each team to find the business, which is not a good idea, well I do have in mind to add businesses directly from the API, like so:

```
$teams = Team::with('business')->get();
```

And in the view do so: `tm.teams.business.name`, but I would not like so, cz I dont want to load businesses each team I display teams. There might be cases where I dont need to show always business for each team. suppose I have millions of teams and attaching business would make the query run heavier.

I would appreciate a lot, if someone would give me any tips on this, what would be the best practice to do.

Comment: Don't know the syntax of the query that fetches the business, but generally, in your backend could be created a query that returns the datasource of teams containing also the business name, done by a sql join of the two tables of teams and business.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik, I do already have businesses for each team by using the ->with('business') for each team... But I dont know if this is the best solution to go,  let say I have a case where I only need to show teams without businesses, and a case where I show teams+business, I just dont want to have other data added in the query if I dont need them, as they will make the query loading slowly. isnt it?

Comment: So my question basically is, should I handle this from the server or make a seperate call for each team listed from the client side? Obviously this should be not done by client as there will be lots of requests and that might even slow down more the site... If I have to handle this from server, than how would I do that thing with not always loading businesses when not needed... thnx

Comment: if it is just two table join and the relationship is N:1 to the parent table, and the foreign key has an index, than it could be ok.

Comment: yes the relationship is N:1, THNX

Comment: What would you do if the relationship was N:N in this case? or I had to attach more relationship entity to the base entity?

Comment: Does your server technology allow to expose multiple API methods for getting teams, one method for getting teams with businesses and another one without them?

Comment: If it was N:N, it could depend on the volume of data - for example if the data of teams were paged with a max page size, on the average count of child records to a single parent record, the way the data is displayed and edited - if it is displayed all at once or it is a master detail with data fetched on demand.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik, Actually I did something for that to allow that functionality by just adding the relationship to the query string so my request becomes so: teams/1?rel=business, and in the back end I iterate thru the rel array and for each element give i atach the elemtn as parameter to with()... so i dont need to have two methods for this. But I am still not happy with the solution... I have the feeling that there might be a better solution for this case...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("TeamController",function($scope){
  var tm = this;
  tm.teams = [
    
        {
          id:0,
          name:"A",
          
        },
        {
          id:1,
          name:"B",
          
        },
        {
          id:2,
          name:"C",
          
        }
  
  
  ];
  tm.business = [
    {name:"a"},
    {name:"b"},
    {name:"c"}
  ];
  
  tm.getTeamBusiness = function(id){
      return tm.business[id].name;
  }
 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TeamController as tm">
   <div ng-repeat="team in tm.teams">
      <a href="">{{team.name}} - <span ng-bind="tm.getTeamBusiness(team.id)"></span></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying I should once get all teams, and make another call where I get all businesses, and then get businesses based on team id?

If so, I should probably add more logic with the business table, as it just does not know which business to pick by giving only team id. like u did. it's like you have to go thru each element in business array and see which object has the team id....

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-bind` directive:

```
<a href="">{{team.name}} - 
    <span ng-bind="tm.getTeamBusiness(team.id)"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: same thing, still site becomes unresponsible even I use ng-bind instead

Comment: I think I should probably stick with that handling from the server side, using with('business') as it works fine. Just thought there was any other better solution...